# YAML echo date time

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to YAML. I am trying to save Date/Time to a variable. and substract with `2000-01-01`. How can I do this. Finally it'll echo to console.

What I tried:

```
   ...
   d1: $(Get-Date -Format "YYYYMMDD")
   d2: $d1 - $(2000-01-01 -Format "YYYYMMDD")

 steps:
 
 - script: echo '$(d1)'
 - script: echo '$(d2)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in `date` variable/function but you could use PowerShell script to [set the variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell):

```yaml
steps:
- pwsh: |
    $d1 = Get-Date
    $d2 = $d1 - (Get-Date -Year 2000 -Month 01 -Day 01)
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=d1]$($d1.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=d2]$($d2.Days)"
- pwsh: echo '$(d1)'
- pwsh: echo '$(d2)'
```